# To say "You should use X for Y and Z only"

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-structure

Is this sentence correct? (Yes, it's a list now, just for convenience. It will be normal sentence).

> E.g., you can use `[discrete]` for section titles only, `NOTE` for plain paragraphs or `====` blocks only, `[quote]` and `[verse]` for `____` blocks only.

Here is the confusing part:

> `NOTE` for plain paragraphs or `====` blocks only.

It's assumed that `NOTE` couldn't be used for anything except plain paragraphs and `====` blocks.

- Should I use "or" or "and"?
- Should I use "only"?

Comment: I don't understand any of this. But it doesn't really seem to be about learning English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NOTE for plain paragraphs or ==== blocks only.

You don't need "only" here. It seems really fine without it.

> E.g., you can use [discrete] for section titles only, NOTE for plain paragraphs or ==== blocks only, [quote] and [verse] for ____ blocks only.

"Only" seems very redundant in your paragraph. I suggest you omit it and rewrite your paragraph like this:

> For example, you can use [discrete] for section titles, NOTE for plain paragraphs or ==== blocks, and [quote] and [verse] for ____ blocks only.

"Only" in the last sentence is suitable since the previous one has two choices while this one has only one choice which happened to be mentioned before.